# Ubuntu gives black/no graphics after waking up from sleep

Tags: graphics, sleep

First,though this is a duplicate question,but i am asking because the other posts didnt help me,and my case is a little different i guess.

This problem is not recent but since 4-5 ubuntu releases...

When i put my system to sleep,it goes to sleep but when wakes up the screen is totally blank.
At this moment the real OS is awake as from a diff system,i can do ssh and even tried to play an mp3 file through mplayer and the music played through the speakers.

So the real issue is that the graphics system is not waking up.

I can debug whats wrong and can compare few things before the sleep and after wakeup,but i dont know what tools would help me to see whats wrong with the graphics hardware not waking up.

So please help me debug this problem.

PS: I am on ATI x700 Mobility Radeon Graphics.

Edit: Logs links:
Before log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/607342/

After log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/607346/

Comment: Can you post your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` and `/var/log/kern.log` files? Does your system respons on toggling Caps Lock? Can you switch to another TTY by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1?

Comment: i have attached the logs for before going to sleep and after waking up when the screen is blank. And yes,the Caps lock key is working as it should.

Comment: Can you put the logs on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ please? I hate mediafire etc for waiting and adverts. Are you able switch to an other TTY using Ctrl + Alt + F1?

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com DONE.pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 does nothing... as far as i remember this stopped since a couple of ubuntu releases.. i think ubuntu disabled this hot-key combination since long.. i am on natty.

Comment: what happens if you close and (a couple of seconds later) open the lid? If your system then does come back up: I solved this by using the recommended nVidia driver (and not the newest)

Comment: @Rinzwind: he has an ATI card.

Comment: @Rinzwind nvdia drivers for ATI hardware.. i dont think thats possible anyhow!

Comment: @Lekensteyn @ashishsony > **I** < have an nVidia card in my system and > **I** < solved it on my system by using the lateste nVidia driver. Search+replace nVidia for your own system ;)

Comment: I have near the same issue. But I don't use sleep. The display blank occures, only sometimes when I close my IBM ThinkPad T42's screen... - I'm looking for solution... I have no "other driver" required graphic card...

Answer (score 1):

The only suspicious message I found in your logs (`kern.log`) was:

```
[drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id
```

I'm not sure whether this is

Other things to try:

- Update your system!
- Restart GDM over SSH:

  ```
  sudo stop gdm
  sudo start gdm
  ```

  (I had issues with just `sudo restart gdm`)
- Reloading the `radeon` driver:

  ```
  sudo rmmod radeon
  sudo modprobe radeon
  ```
- If you've SSH access, you can shutdown the machine by running:

  ```
  sudo shutdown -h now
  ```

  If not, you can try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> combined with (in order): <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> with small delays (2 secs should be fine) between these. (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#.22Raising_Elephants.22_mnemonic_device) for explanation)

Comment: once i do sudo stop gdm i cant do anything from the ssh terminal.so not able to do sudo start gdm/

secondly,while doing "sudo rmmod radeon" i get ERROR: Module radeon is in use/
with "sudo rmmod -f radeon" i get ERROR: Removing 'radeon': Resource temporarily unavailable/

and i dont understand what do you mean by this:
When shutting down, use sudo shutdown -h now on SSH. If you can't do that, use REISUB/

Thanks for Helping!

Comment: It looks like a driver issue then since GDM is blocking. Try filing a bug at launchpad.net.

Comment: launchpad.net is so complex.. i have no idea how to file a bug..this is a big frustation in relation to ubuntu... such an easy to use OS but such a pain to file bugs.. which equates to.. the humans,for which ubuntu is designed for cant file bugs. Please if you have time do file it for me.Thanks for helping though.

Comment: @ashishsony: I find LP very easy to use compared to Bugzilla (used by Mozilla and others). In a default Kubuntu installation, a bookmark is added for reporting bugs, I expect a similar feature for Ubuntu. Before reporting, you've to determine what package the bug should be reporting to. [Bugs on xserver-xorg-video-ati](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati). To report a bug, see [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/6969)

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Thanks... i have successfully reported the bug.Ya its easy to report bugs only when u know what package is involved.. as you indicated:xserver-xorg-video-ati..

Comment: If you're not sure, you could always ask it on the IRC channel #ubuntu-bugs on irc.freenode.net

Comment: @Lekensteyn: oh..ic.. thanks.. ill check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with NVidia graphics on my laptop and had traced it to the screen being locked while going to sleep. Shall I manually lock the screen before putting the system to sleep, it resumes just fine. Could you please confirm if this helps in your situation?