# Why does my Dell D620 laptop not resume from suspend?

Tags: 16.04, suspend, dell, power-management

Summary: It appears to me that the laptop is shutting off before the suspend processes complete, and then it completes the suspend processes after resuming and consequently becomes confused and crashes. Is my interpretation of [the log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26142998/) correct? How do I solve this problem?

~~~

Pressing the power button to resume from suspend, the screen remains blank. It does not appear "to resume correctly but leave the screen turned off" because pressing the power button once after this failed resume turns off the computer, whereas in a normal session pressing the power button once has no effect.

[This Sept. 2012 answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/190733/761477) did not solve my problem. Here is the output to confirm that I changed the setting (the problem occurs whether `false` or `true`):

```
user@computer:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
false
user@computer:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
user@computer:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
true
```

Is there some particular info from the output of the list hardware package `lshw` that I should share here? Here is some info I saw about the display:

```
    *-display:0 UNCLAIMED
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 03
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:eff00000-eff7ffff ioport:eff8(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:efec0000-efefffff
    *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
         description: Display controller
         product: Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
         version: 03
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:eff80000-efffffff
```

Following the instruction of a comment to [this May 2011 question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42664/ubuntu-gives-black-no-graphics-after-waking-up-from-sleep?rq=1), [here is an excerpt](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26142998/) from `/var/log/kern.log`. Corresponding actions that generated this log:

- 9:40 suspend laptop
- 9:43 pressed the power button to resume
- 9:43 waited a moment to verify the screen remained blank
- 9:4? pressed the power button again to turn off the device
- 9:4? waited a few seconds then pressed the power button again to start up.

It appears to me that the laptop is shutting off before the suspend processes complete, and then it completes the suspend processes after resuming and consequently becomes confused and crashes. Is my interpretation of the log correct? How do I solve this problem?

It may also be noteworthy that I apparently do not have a `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` file.

Comment: Since Ubuntu 16.04 and Systemd for two laptops in a row Suspend partially runs and goes to sleep. When it wakes up, it completes suspend and immediately resumes. I had [posted a 100 point bounty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828486/systemd-suspends-system-but-upon-resume-kernel-then-enters-sleep-and-wake-up) on this before and never got a clear answer. As far as `pm-suspend.log` goes-it's not on my system either. I think it's obsoleted technology but not positive.

Comment: Do you have `swap` space defined, more `swap` than you have RAM? What does the `pm-is-supported` command tell you? My `Dell Latitude D630` suspends just fine.

Comment: Output of that command is `pm-is-supported [--suspend | --hibernate | --suspend-hybrid ]`. There is no output after `pm-is-supported --suspend`: It merely returns the command prompt. `swapon -s` indicates `/dev/sda6` partition (so it's defined there, right?) with size 2.08 million; HardInfo reports 2.05 million kB memory. So the swap partition is both defined and larger than my total RAM, right?

Comment: All the above are good ideas but nobody yet seems to have noticed the "unclaimed" (= no drivers). Intel Graphics drivers are installed by default but situations like this may happen. Before anything else I suggest installing the drivers: `sudo apt install  xserver-xorg-video-intel`

Comment: @MichaelBay, that returned `xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1.2).`as well as a suggestion to execute `sudo apt autoremove` to remove automatically-installed no longer required packages. Should I remove these packages, or might `apt` be mistaken in declaring them unneeded? (For example, `linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-93`.) The output finished with, `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`

Comment: The orphaned packages can be removed and in your case they're only old kernels. Totally unrelated to your issue though, removing them or not will change nothing.